# Collect selected values within dictionary that may exist or not

Tags: python, dictionary

Given this dictionary:

```
{
    "id": "a4f148b7-60ec-4948-98ed-7adc3d998440",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "aa524785-968c-43c4-bd1a-94c1d2263b35",
            "name": "FIRST OBJECT",
            "modifiers": [
                {
                    "id": "49d8792f-35b1-4cf6-ba95-071c87b0bae6",
                    "name": "FIRST SUBOBJECT",
                    "notes": "Notes on that"
                },
                {
                    "id": "f7d427d0-1509-4a07-8896-bf7f40bbc808",
                    "name": "SECOND SUBOBJECT",
                }
            ],
            "notes": "Notes on the main object",
            "categories": [
                "First Category","Second Category"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2f8a7457-2741-412f-82b3-6180433eeeec",
            "name": "Another Object",
            "categories": [
                "First Category"
            ]
        }
}
```

I'm trying to print out some of the values, but I think the code is getting too complicated with all "try" and "except" for determining wether a key exists. Like the "notes" or "modifiers".
Yet, it's not working:

```
for rowList in iter(dicioBiblio['rows']):
#    print (rowList['name'])
    list.append([rowList['name'],
    [item for item in rowList['categories'] if rowList['categories']]])
    try:
        list[-1].append(rowList['notes'])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        for idx , modifier in rowList['modifiers']:
            print (idx,modifier)
            list[-1].append([item['name'] for item in iter(rowList['modifiers'])])
            try:
                list[-1][idx].append(modifier['notes'])
            except KeyError:
                pass
    except:
        pass
```

I'm pretty confident there is a better way to do it. The intention is to get a list like:

```
[['First Object',['First Category','Second Category'],[['First Subobject','Notes on that'],['Second Subobject','']],'Notes on the main object'],['Another Object','First Category','','']]
```

Comment: You can use `rowList.get('notes', 'some default value')` to get a default value if the key doesn't exist. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). Or use `if 'notes' in rowList` to check if the key exists.

Comment: @Kemp, that will do! =) thank you! I should've knonw better.